# Category images are not displaying in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, categories

I have categories list with there respective images. I am able to get the category name and description but I am not getting the category image. I tried the below code.

```
<ul>
  <?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'parent'     => 0,
        'hide_empty' => 0, 
    ) );
    
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
        {
        $cat_ID        = $category->term_id;
        $category_name = $category->name;
        $category_desc = $category->description;
        //$category_img = $category->category_images;
        $category_images = get_option('category_images');?>

       <li>
       <?php
       echo $category_name;
       echo $category_desc;
       echo $category_images; //display the path of image for temporary
          ?>         
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

I tried below code as well

```
 $category_image = '';
  if ( is_array( $category_images ) && array_key_exists( get_query_var('cat'), $category_images ) ){
  $category_image = $category_images[get_query_var('cat') 
}
```

I am getting the image but only getting first image.

var_dump($category)

[image]

Comment: How is your image saved? if you `var_dump($category)` in your `foreach`, do you see anything regarding image srces?

Comment: @Stender, I used custom code in the function.php. I am able to add and edit the image. I checked var_dump($category) in foreach I am not getting the image.

Comment: @Stender, I added the output(only one) in the question

Comment: If the image is not in the var_dump(), then we need to know, where you save it instead, what are you using to add the image - are you saving it as post meta for the image, or an ACF field? etc.

Comment: @Stender, I refer this link to add image  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352455/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-category-and-display-image-on-category-page

Comment: I store the image in wp_options table

Comment: And if you `var_dump(get_option('category_images'))` I suspect that it will associated with the term_id as index. if so - it might be `var_dump($category_images[$cat_ID]);`

Comment: @Stender, Yes, I used var_dump($category_images[$cat_ID]) and it's solved my issue.. Thank you so much. Please add the answer so that i can refer this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments in the question, you store the images in the option table, as an array indexed by the term id.

Meaning that if you want to fetch that array entry/image, you need to call it like this

`<?php echo $category_images[$cat_ID];?>`

If you have stored is as an array, with alt texts, src, name etc. you can access that array like this

`<?php echo $category_images[$cat_ID]['exampleIndexAltText'];?>`

You were jut lacking the last logical part of, how to retrieve what you have stored.

Comment: If possible then can you help me in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279899/can-we-create-a-category-list-page-in-wordpress/